# Is there a web browser for the 1st generation Kindle Fire that uses TLS1.2 or higher?

Tags: browser, https

Various websites are starting to fail to load in the built-in Silk web browser, and I've tracked the issue down to the fact that Silk uses only TLS 1.0.

TLS 1.0/1.1 is outdated and insecure to such an extent that major websites have begun refusing such connections outright.

I asked Amazon support if there were any solutions or workarounds, but since the 1st gen Fire is no longer supported there really isn't one. I looked at sideloading a different browser like Firefox, but the APK refuses to launch (I'm assuming my version of Android is too old.)

I'd rather not throw out a device that still works perfectly if I can reasonably avoid it.

Comment: If you insist on using the device (rather than just ditching it for a new one), consider flashing a custom ROM of higher Android version, with the additional benefit of jumping out of Amazon's ecosystem (i.e. use Play Store normally, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox 47 can be installed on the 1st generation Kindle Fire. It supports TLS 1.2.

Download link: [Mozilla's official FTP](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mobile/releases/47.0/android-api-9/en-US/fennec-47.0.en-US.android-arm.apk).